# Is newlib for building cross compiler for powerpc e500mc mandatory?

Tags: gcc, powerpc

I am trying to build a cross compiler for PowerPC e500mc with target powerpc-e500mc-eabi. As some websites mentioned, i built an bootstrap compiler first. and then tried to compile newlib with it. But i got some error like,

```
/bin/sh: powerpc-e500mc-eabi-cc: command not found
```

I want to know, can we directly compile GCC cross compiler without newLib. Also, can anyone tell me the exact pre-requisites for powerpc e500mc architecture. I have GMP, MPC, MPFR, BinUtils not sure whether newLib required or not.

Comment: If anyone can provide exact steps with all dependencies, that would be appreciable, facing same issues while compiling GCC toolchain for ARCH=powerpc for e500mc.

Answer (score 1):

You can build gcc without any C library, there is no need for newlib. Please find a list of dependencies from a crosstool-ng build below.

## 1. Alternatives

- You can build everything manually, what you obviously attempted to do. This is possible but there are various constraints to keep in mind, for instance builds might fail if your filesystem is not case sensitive or if you build inside your source directory. Besides all the dependencies and their versions.
- You let crosstool-ng build your cross toolchain. Crosstool-ng is mostly self-contained with few external dependencies. It will download and build all dependencies in the right versions for you, and it comes with various sample configurations. It will check for obstacles like a case insensitive filesystem. It lets you configure your cross toolchain in a similar way you configure a Linux kernel. I've built various cross toolchains by means of it for several years on several host systems without trouble, including Linux, OS X (homebrew) and Windows (cygwin). You find it here: http://crosstool-ng.org/.

I'm going to line out the steps that it takes to build a cross toolchain by means of crosstool-ng. I tested this setup on Windows (cygwin) today with the crosstool-ng from git.

## 2. Download crosstool-ng, build and install it.

Follow the steps in

> docs/2 - Installing crosstool-NG.txt.

## 3. Configure your cross toolchain.

Follow the steps in

> docs/3 - Configuring a toolchain.txt.

## 4. Example

```
mkdir powerpc-e500v2-eabi
cd powerpc-e500v2-eabi
ct-ng powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe
```

The last step will create a configuration from a sample which I thought is similar enough to what you want. In the next step, we will adapt this configuration, the criteria are

- no operating system
- no C library
- EABI
- you want e500mc, the sample is e500v2. I leave it up to you to adapt the configuration to it.

### 4.1. Configuration

```
ct-ng menuconfig
```

- Operating System

  - Target OS

    - Select bare-metal
- C-library

  - C library

    - Select none
- Target options

  - ABI

    - Select EABI
- C-Compiler

  - gcc version

    - Select 5.1.0 (the sample configured a gcc 4.6.4
      here)
  - Deselect C++ (since you do not want a C library
    either and it'd pull extra dependencies)
- Debug facilities

  - Deselect gdb (unless you want it, can pull extra dependencies)

### 4.2. Build

```
ct-ng build.4
```

Crosstool-ng will download and build the following dependencies.

- gmp-6.0.0a
- mpfr-3.1.2
- isl-0.14
- mpc-1.0.2
- binutils-2.25
- gcc-5.1.0

It will install the cross toolchain in

```
${HOME}/x-tools/powerpc-e500v2-eabi.
```

You can specify a different install prefix in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This build issue can be fixed by creating a symlink **powerpc-e500mc-eabi-cc** pointing to **powerpc-e500mc-eabi-gcc**.